# Bitfinex REST API v2.0 modify orders

Tags: api, bitfinex

I am not sure if this is the right place for this kind of question, but there is no general crypto currency stack ...

I am developing an application which accesses Bitfinex data and also should be able to modify Bitfinex data and I am using the REST API to achieve this.

But all endpoints I see in https://bitfinex.readme.io/v2/reference are only read endpoints and do not modify orders or create/delete orders. Is this not possible in v2? Can I simply use the v1 endpoints for this or is this deprecated? I don't want to use the Websocket which is able to modify /create new orders.

Answer (score 1):

Update orders are exclusive to Websocket APIs in version 2, so you have to either use them or use v1 rest APIs which is not recommended.